# 2 tick boxes appearing below comments

Tags: posts, comments, blog

In my site I have two tick boxes appearing above each other underneath the comments section.

I have tried disabling pingbacks etc.

How do I remove these?

example - http://vikingsandc.co.uk/2012/11/test-text-test-text/

Answer (score 0):

Those are "subscribe" checkboxes. View source and you can see them and the rest of the content.

```
<p class="comment-subscription-form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="subscribe_comments" id="subscribe_comments" value="subscribe" style="width: auto; -moz-appearance: checkbox; -webkit-appearance: checkbox;" /> 
    <label class="subscribe-label" id="subscribe-label" for="subscribe_comments">Notify me of follow-up comments by email.</label></p>
<p class="comment-subscription-form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="subscribe_blog" id="subscribe_blog" value="subscribe" style="width: auto; -moz-appearance: checkbox; -webkit-appearance: checkbox;" /> 
    <label class="subscribe-label" id="subscribe-blog-label" for="subscribe_blog">Notify me of new posts by email.</label>
</p>
```

The text for the checkboxes is hidden because your stylesheet ( http://vikingsandc.co.uk/wp-content/themes/novatorix/css/firebrick.css ) has `#commentform label {display:none}`

I am not sure exactly how to remove them because it is a theme issue, mostly. Look in `comments.php` and look for [`comment_form`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form). I think that is the most likely location for this code. There are [several hooks in `comment_form`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1512) so your theme may be using one or more those to add the checkboxes. Maybe look for a callback to [`wp_list_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) as well.